# How to save audacity project without audio embedded in it

Tags: audacity

First time using audacity in years. I downloaded the latest version, imported a 2GB audio file, and when I "save as" the project, it saves the audio in the project folder, so that the project is around 2gb.

I recall there used to be an option to reference the audio at the location you open it from, so that the project directory is much smaller. Since I save my source files and the project, I can't afford the space of storing the audio effectively twice.

I can't find the option to do this any more, or anything in the online manual or searching google. Is this still possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try, but on import you can choose [not to make a copy of the audio file](https://wit.audacityteam.org/scroller-contents/importing_audio.html) (see Importing Uncompressed Audio Files) but to read them directly on the original file. I did not test, but I would say that if you open your file this way, it should not be saved as a copy in your project upon saving.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for this- I recall this dialog from last time I used Audacity, but I do not seem to get it on a fresh install of 2.4.2.

Comment: @clearedPerson maybe check the preferences?

Comment: Nothing about importing in the preferences, and all dialogs/warnings are still enabled. I'm hoping this options wasn't removed but I can't find any indication it exists anymore...

Comment: @clearedPerson Arf... Hope you will find a solution!

Comment: @clearedPerson It looks like the option was removed.

Comment: That option has indeed gone away with the new Audacity file format

Answer (score 1):

This option was removed in Audacity version 2.3.3, see: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/on_demand_loading.html